# Graphical servers monitoring

Tags: server, monitoring

I am using Ubuntu with Apache, PHP, Mysql, SSH ,Mail, FTP ... servers. Is there any application that monitor these servers activities? How can I monitor all servers be actived or see any activity on each server? CPU usages or disk failaure warnning?

Comment: Hi there! I guess nagios or a zabbix service can do what you require. But I found it painful receiving anonymous notifications. That's me!!! May be you'll find it useful.